# Cell selection issue with EasyTableView

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitableview

I have what must be a simple problem with EasyTableView  (https://github.com/alekseyn/EasyTableView)

I have a number of horizontally scrolling tables that function properly.

I am able to select a cell and perform a segue, however, once the new view controller is dismissed, I am no longer able to select that cell and perform the same action until I have selected another cell in the same table.

My question is:  How can I deselect previously selected the cell programmatically to renable this particular action.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have this exact same problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selectedIndexPath is intentionally persistent in case a user scrolls the selected tableview cell offscreen and then back again. If you don't want this persistence please add the line shown below, after the delegate method (in EasyTableView.m):

```
- (void)setSelectedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (![_selectedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]) {
        NSIndexPath *oldIndexPath = [_selectedIndexPath copy];

        _selectedIndexPath = indexPath;

        UITableViewCell *deselectedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:oldIndexPath];
        UITableViewCell *selectedCell   = (UITableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:_selectedIndexPath];

    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(easyTableView:selectedView:atIndexPath:deselectedView:)]) {
        UIView *selectedView = [selectedCell viewWithTag:CELL_CONTENT_TAG];
        UIView *deselectedView = [deselectedCell viewWithTag:CELL_CONTENT_TAG];

        [delegate easyTableView:self
                   selectedView:selectedView
                    atIndexPath:_selectedIndexPath
                 deselectedView:deselectedView];

        // Add this line here!
        _selectedIndexPath = nil;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!  I did a workaround at an earlier point, but will try this.

Comment: Quick update - that fixed my problem in the original code.  Thank you very much!